# Add ctx in on_member_join Event

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So im fairly new to this and this is my first time asking question.

I want my bot to create a new channel when a member joins and make it so only that specific member can view it. Im planning on adding more to it so that it deletes after specific time. I've made it so that it creates a channl but to work with channel permissions I need to have ctx which i cannot define in on_member_join function.

Attaching the code for reference, and yes I'm working with cogs.

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_member_join(self,member : discord.Member):
    ChannelName = member.name
    guild = member.guild
    
    await guild.create_text_channel(name = '{}'.format(ChannelName))
    overwrites = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.default_role)
    overwrites.read_messages, overwrites.send_messages = False, False
    await ctx.channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrites)
    overwrites = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.member)
    overwrites.send_messages, overwrites.read_messages = True, True
    await guild.channel.set_permissions(ctx.member, overwrite=overwrites)
    await ctx.send ('Success!!')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`create_text_channel`](http://create_text_channel) returns the [TextChannel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=create_text_channel#discord.TextChannel) which you can use to replace `ctx.channel` as `ctx.channel` is the channel that the command was called from. For the default_role it exists from [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) which can be accessed from `member.guild.default_role`

The code below should work:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
  async def on_member_join(self,member : discord.Member):
    ChannelName = member.name
    guild = member.guild
    
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name = '{}'.format(ChannelName))
    overwrites = channel.overwrites_for(member.guild.default_role)
    overwrites.read_messages, overwrites.send_messages = False, False
    await channel.set_permissions(member.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrites)
    overwrites = channel.overwrites_for(member)
    overwrites.send_messages, overwrites.read_messages = True, True
    await channel.set_permissions(member, overwrite=overwrites)
    await channel.send ('Success!!')
```

Comment: Since your answer is 8 seconds earlier then mine and more detailed, I deleted mine :)

Comment: I know @Abdulaziz your one had some faults in I was just about write a comment about

Comment: Thanks a lott. I just had to remove guild from the last second line as guild has no attribute channel. Otherwise it works thanks a lot for helping out. I've edited your answer.